# How to Pass data from Ajax to Controller method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following javascript code:

```
 <script>
  function RequestData() {
    var Nos = $("#search").val();
    var DataIntervals = $("#txtDataInterval").val();
    var StartDates = $("#start_date").val();
    var EndDates = $("#end_date").val();
    if (Nos != null && DataIntervals != null && StartDates != null && EndDates != null) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: 'ExtractData/ExtractData',
            data: {
                'No': Nos,
                'DataInterval': DataIntervals,
                'StartDate': StartDates,
                'EndStart': EndDates
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("The Query Has Completed Successfully.");
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert("Something Went Wrong Please Try Again." + e);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please Select All The Required Fields and Try Again.");
    }
  }
</script>
```

I'm trying to pass to parameters to C# method but they always null.
Here is my C# method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ExtractData(string No, string DataInterval, string StartDate, string EndStart)
{
  string x = No;
  return View();
}
```

What is it I'm doing wrong that makes this method parameters to always be null?

Comment: You should create an object (model) that contains all the parameters. Then you can use it as parameter.
You should also use the [FromBody] attribute before the parameter to ensure it will be filled from the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried serializing your data?

```
var data = {
    No: Nos,
    DataInterval: DataIntervals,
    StartDate: StartDates,
    EndStart: EndDates
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: 'ExtractData/ExtractData',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("The Query Has Completed Successfully.");
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("Something Went Wrong Please Try Again." + e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, What I use for Ajax call to the server is that I have created two methods called "PostMyData" and "GetMyData" as you can see below. They receive three parameters that are:

data: that is to be sent to the server

URL: this is the URL of the API that you like to call

SuccessFunction: this is the callback function that retrieves the response

Note: You can edit this function as you like.

```
// Post Data
    function PostMyData(data, url, SuccessFunction) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //async: false,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: SuccessFunction,
        failure: function (response) {
          //location.href = 'Shared/Error';
          console.log(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
          //location.href = 'Shared/Error';
          console.log(response.responseText);
        }
      });
    }

    // Get Data
    function GetMyData(url, SuccessFunction) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: SuccessFunction,
        failure: function (response) {
          //location.href = 'Shared/Error';
          console.log(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
          //location.href = 'Shared/Error';
          console.log(response.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
```

Usage Example (Your Code):

```
 const obj = { 'No': Nos, 'DataInterval': DataIntervals, 'StartDate': StartDates, 'EndStart': EndDates}

 PostMyData(obj, '/ExtractData/ExtractData', (res) => {
      alert('working')
    })
```